# Check List1 for duplicates and preserve information in List2 and List3

Tags: python, list

this is my the first question here. I hope someone can help me.
I have 3 Lists (L1,L2,L3), from which 1 needs to be checked for duplicates. Those duplicates should be summarized as one value.
Example:

```
L1 = [10.000, 20.000, 20.000, 50.000, 100.000]
L2 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
L3 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

L1 needs to become: L1 = [10.000, 20.000, 50.000, 100.000]
The values in L2 and L3, where the 20.000 duplicate is, should be added up.
L2 must be: L2 = [1, 2, 1, 1]
L3 must be: L3 = [0, 0, 0, 1]

I summarized the L1 list:

```
import collections
counter =collections.Counter(L1)
print(counter.keys())
```

Now I need to sum up the values in List L2 and L3, where the duplicates were.
I hope my question is comprehensible.

Comment: how exactly does `L3` work?

Comment: L3 contains information about the sample (L1). For example the value 1 in L3 means, there was 1 defect in 100.000 sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If and only if L1 is sorted**, you can use this:

```
L1 = [10.000, 20.000, 20.000, 50.000, 100.000]
L2 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
L3 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

doubel_indices = [i for i in range(len(L1)-1) if L1[i] == L1[i+1]] #check the position of a double value (therefore L1 needs to be sorted here)

for i in sorted(doubel_indices, reverse=True):
    L2[i+1] += L2[i]    #add the values
    L3[i+1] += L3[i]    #add the values
    del L1[i]           #delete the dublicate position
    del L2[i]           #delete the dublicate position
    del L3[i]           #delete the dublicate position

print(L1)
print(L2)
print(L3)
```

**output**

```
[10.0, 20.0, 50.0, 100.0]
[1, 2, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the most pythonic approach I can come up with-

```py
from collections import Counter

# Initial values
L1 = [10.000, 20.000, 20.000, 50.000, 100.000]
L2 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
L3 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

# Create a dict, each key is unique, and each value is the number of appearances of said key in given list (L1)
L1_counter = Counter(L1)
# Create a dict, where each key is unique, and from L1, each value is from L3, cross references according to position
# Assign the values of said list to L3
L3 = list(dict(zip(L1, L3)).values())
# Create a list from the keys of aforementioned counter, results in a list of unique items
# Basically the same original L1, with duplicates removed
# The values are the counts of each key, that's exactly what L2 should be
L1, L2 = list(L1_counter.keys()), list(L1_counter.values())

print(f'L1 is {L1}')
print(f'L2 is {L2}')
print(f'L3 is {L3}')
```

Output-

```
L1 is [10.0, 20.0, 50.0, 100.0]
L2 is [1, 2, 1, 1]
L3 is [0, 0, 0, 1]
```

**Note**: This assumes-

- The initial length of `L1`, `L2` and `L3` are the same
- In case of duplicate values, `L3`'s initial value for all duplicates is the same. For example, `L3` has 0 for both 20.000. It must not differ. Frankly, that'd make no sense. 2 different values for the same thing?